# .net app not getting exe parameters when launched from web browser

Tags: .net

I have a vb app that uses command line arguments.  I can run the app and it recognizes the args when I run it through a shortcut using "C:\myApp\myapp.exe -b:"somesetting" -a:"othersetting".  If I need to launch the app from html (such as html embedded email)  I create the link as:

```
<a href="file:///c:\myApp\myapp.exe?-b=somesetting&-a=othersetting">click here </a>
```

It launches my app but doesn't pick up the arguments.  The vb code that grabs the arguments looks like:

```
Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
For cnt As Integer = 1 To args.Length - 1

    Select Case args(cnt).Substring(0, 2).ToLower
        Case "-b"       ' do stuff
        Case "-a"       ' do other stuff
           setvar = args(cnt).Substring(3)
    End Select

Next
```

Any one know how to grab the args when passed in from a URL Query  String I would appreciate help.

Comment: running an exe from a clickable web link is a scary concept...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use your own custom URL protocol handler and use that in your anchor tag. You will need to update the client registry for this to work.
So you would have something like this:

```
<a href="myProt:myParam">click here </a>
```

For more info, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15634/Custom-Hyperlinks-Using-Asynchronous-Pluggable-Pro).

Another way is to use the .Net Click Once framework. For info on that see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545083/Custom-HyperLinks-Using-a-Generic-Protocol-Handler).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.  After much reading I found a simple solution.  That is I created an lnk file using WshShell in the .net app that generates the email and attached the lnk file instead of embedding a link to the exe in the html of the email.  May not look as pretty ... but it works.